# how to put checkbox selected options in a List using spring form tags

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp, tags

Good day.

I have a class named Group which is composed of a List.

```
<c:forEach items="${group.accounts}" var="data">
        <div class="account-no-list">
            <form:checkbox name="account-no-checkbox" value="${data.accountNumber}" path="accounts"/> 
            <span>${data.accountNumber}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"><!--  --></div>
</c:forEach>
```

the code above is what i am trying in order to put the selected options among the checkboxes to the List inside group but it is not working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks stackoverflow.

Comment: by the way, List is composed of Account objects. -> List<Account>

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the 'checked' attribute instead of value. And for that you can use EL

Like so:

```
<form:checkbox name="account-no-checkbox" value="" checked="${data.accountNumber eq true ? 'true' : 'false'}" />
```